# Properly way of writing conditional expressions in PHP

Tags: php, performance, expression

I have rather small question. I've seen a lot of code examples where coders use

```
if (null == $item)
```

instead of

```
if ($item == null)
```

Can anybody say, what is the difference between this two expressions?

Comment: Nothing. There is no difference. Some people prefer the constant on the left, because it causes an error if you typo `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: There's no right/wrong way. There's just opinions. Some people advocate the "constant" value first, so that if you accidentally write `=` instead of `==`, then you'll get a runtime error instead of trashing your variable.

Comment: that's the answer i was searching for! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if (null == $item)` (constant on left side) is called "Yoda conditions" and is used to prevent errors if you use the assignment (=) operator by misstake, instead of the equal comparison operator (==).

Answer (score 1):

[New Programming Jargon](http://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/)

They are both equivalent as far as doing the same thing.  However if you get in the habit of forming your condition statements as yoda conditions, then you won't accidentally assign a value to your variable.

```
if ('something' = $var) { /* this causes an exception */ }

if ($var = 'something') { /* this sets $var to 'something' and executes code between the brackets */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a condition, no matter which way it's written.